# Can I leave Colombia with a cedula in the old format?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, dual-nationality, colombia, colombian-citizens

I currently hold a Colombian cedula (an identity document issued to Colombian citizens) that was issued in 2010. It has holograms but it is not the latest cedula format.

I am a dual American/Colombian citizen, currently in the US but planning to travel to Colombia soon. Would I be ok once it’s time to leave Colombia or do I need to have the latest cedula format? I’m getting conflicting information from family members and I even called the DC consulate and they couldn’t give me a confident answer.

Comment: Are you in the U.S. or Colombia? Do you want to know if you can use it to enter or leave Colombia? Your question indicates "leave Colombia", but then the DC consulate would have no idea about that, you need to ask the local police/immigration/customs department.

Comment: I’m currently in the US. I’m traveling to Colombia soon.  I want to know if it could possibly be an issue upon leaving Colombia